# is it possible to know on which date and time resize2fs was activated on disk

Tags: rhel, disk, vmware, resize2fs

we have rhel machine with disk sdb , and disk OS is sda

before couple days - not sure about the time & date

`resize2fs` was implemented on the disk sdb , so disk sdb expended from 20G to 40G

is it possible to know on which date and time  `resize2fs` was performed ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check shell history?

Set your history to show time & date (only for current session)

```
# HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
```

Check history

```
# history
```

Addionaly, it should get reported by the kernel. Check your `/var/log/messages` file for disk related messages.